# MySQL query is not working on server

Tags: mysql

When I run this query locally via XAMPP, I got the results in my PHP page, but when I run this query from my public server, I see just "0".

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE ent_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')";


if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf(" %d\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
```

MySQL version on the public server is
**5.6.32-78.1**

Logically explanation would be that problem is caused by lower version (some command is not supported) but which one from the $sql?.

Comment: just did it , in first post

Comment: please check once generated query on server directly, i guess you don't have data for given date range.

Comment: Yes there is, in localhost there is some value but on server there is displayed value  0.

Comment: international isssues? Using dates as string is usually wrong pattern